# what's the difference berween &ch_array[0] and ch_array?

Tags: c, arrays, char

When I define:

```
char ch_array[50];
```

1. What's the difference between `&ch_array[0]` and `ch_array`?
2. What if I define like this?

   ```
   char *ch_array = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
   ```

   The problem actually comes from when I use `(&ch_array + 128)` vs. `&ch_array[128]`, when `bcopy(&ch_array + 128, buf, 128);`.
3. I got a segementation fault here, but no fault using `bcopy(&ch_array[128], buf, 128);`, why? Does it have anything to do with the location where the array is stored?

Comment: Your subject and question is different. `&ch_array + 128` is nonsensical.

Comment: Don't ask three questions in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the problem actually comes from when I use `(&ch_array + 128)` vs. `&ch_array[128]`, when `bcopy(&ch_array + 128, buf, 128);`

`ch_array` is an array (an array of 50 `char`, to be precise). `&ch_array[0]` is a pointer to `char`, a pointer to `ch_array`'s initial element.

In most contexts, the array name is converted to a pointer to its initial element, but one of the exceptions<sup>(1)</sup> is when it is the operand of the address operator `&`.

Thus `&ch_array` is a pointer to an array of 50 `char`, and

```
&ch_array + 128
```

is adds `128 * sizeof(char[50])` to the address of `ch_array`. By what we have been given in the question, the addition invokes undefined behaviour, but in practice, usually you will obtain an address `128*50 = 6400` bytes from the start of `ch_array`.

`&ch_array[128]` on the other hand, is a pointer to the 128-th element of the array `ch_array` (that doesn't exist, so it's more undefined behaviour), 128 bytes from the start of `ch_array`.

---

If you define it

```
char *ch_array = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
```

then `ch_array` is a pointer to `char`, and it also has the same value as `&ch_array[0]`, but in contrast to the above, there is no conversion involved.

Then, `&ch_array` is a `char**`, and `&ch_array + 128` would be - without the undefined behaviour that is invoked since `ch_array` is not an element of a sufficiently large `char*` array - a `char**` pointing to a place `128 * sizeof(char*)` bytes behind where `ch_array` is stored.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The exceptions are when an expression of type "array of T" is the operand of the `sizeof` or address (`&`) operators, and when it is a string literal used to initialise a `char` array, or a wide string literal used to initialise a wide character array.

Comment: The `_Alignof` exception doesn't actually exist (that's an error in the N1570 draft of the C11 standard, fixed in the final standard). The `_Alignof` operator does not take an expression as an operand.

Comment: My mistake. In the third question, I actually defined ch_array[256]

Answer (score 1):

```
bcopy(&ch_array[128], buf, 128);
```

is equivalent to

```
bcopy(ch_array+128, buf, 128);
```

but

```
bcopy(&ch_array+128, buf, 128);
```

is something entirely different.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `ch_array` and `&ch_array` are different, whichever definition of `ch_array` you use. `ch_array` and `&ch_array[0]` are almost synonymns, though ocassionally the compiler chokes on `ch_array` but accepts `&ch_array[0]`. `ch_array` and `&ch_array[0]` are both of type `char *`. `&ch_array` is of type `char **`.

`ch_array + 128` is a synonymn for `&ch_array[128]`.  It's not a synonymn for `&ch_array[128]`. The former mean 128 bytes into `ch_array`. The latter means 128 char pointers after the address of `ch_array`, which is likely to be somewhere kind of random; in your case it's not even part of your address space.

Second of all, if you really did define `ch_array[50]` and then access the 128th element, you are asking for a SEGV there too.

Comment: -1 `ch_array` is not of type `char*` it is of type `char[50]`. In most contexts it is converted to `char*` but that is not the same thing.